# Holoviews "Points" working with Datashader but "Curve" is throwing an error

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews, datashader

I'm working with large data (~25million points) in Python in Jupyter Notebook and want to have an interactive graph that also doesn't take forever to load. Using Bokeh gives me the interactivity and Holoviews and Datashader allows the data to be graphed relatively quickly.

Python: 3.7.6
Bokeh: 1.4.0
Holoviews: 1.14.3
Numpy: 1.19.5
Pandas: 1.0.1
Numba: 0.48.0

I have no problem running this example code:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade
hv.extension('bokeh','matplotlib')

n = 100000
dates = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', freq='1T', periods=n)
point = hv.Points((dates,
                  np.random.normal(size=(n,))))
datashade(point, cmap=['red']).opts(width=800)
```

Which gives a nice graph: [image]

But when I switch the Holoviews options from "Points" to "Curve" (which was the original code) like so:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade
hv.extension('bokeh','matplotlib')

n = 100000
dates = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', freq='1T', periods=n)
curve = hv.Curve((dates,
                  np.random.normal(size=(n,))))
datashade(curve, cmap=['red']).opts(width=800)
```

I am given this long error:

```py
WARNING:param.dynamic_operation: Callable raised "TypingError('Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\nInternal error at <numba.typeinfer.StaticGetItemConstraint object at 0x0000021D40ACEC88>.\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1mtuple index out of range\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: typing of static-get-item at C:\\Users\\HornLab\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\datashader\\glyphs\\line.py (653)\x1b[0m\nEnable logging at debug level for details.\n\x1b[1m\nFile "..\\..\\..\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\datashader\\glyphs\\line.py", line 653:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1mdef _xiaolinwu(i, x0, x1, y0, y1, append, *aggs_and_cols):\n    <source elided>\n    agg = aggs_and_cols[0]\n\x1b[1m    cols = aggs_and_cols[1]\n\x1b[0m    \x1b[1m^\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _xiaolinwu at 0x0000021D2E0B98B8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[2] During: typing of call at <draw_segment> (33)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _xiaolinwu at 0x0000021D2E0B98B8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[4] During: typing of call at <draw_segment> (33)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m\nFile "<draw_segment>", line 33:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function draw_segment at 0x0000021D4063DAF8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[2] During: typing of call at <perform_extend_line> (13)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function draw_segment at 0x0000021D4063DAF8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[4] During: typing of call at <perform_extend_line> (13)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m\nFile "<perform_extend_line>", line 13:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function perform_extend_line at 0x0000021D4063DE58>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[2] During: typing of call at <extend_cpu> (10)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function perform_extend_line at 0x0000021D4063DE58>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[4] During: typing of call at <extend_cpu> (10)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m\nFile "<extend_cpu>", line 10:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>\x1b[0m\n')".
Invoked as dynamic_operation(height=400, scale=1.0, width=400, x_range=None, y_range=None)
WARNING:param.dynamic_operation: Callable raised "TypingError('Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1m\x1b[1mFailed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)\nInternal error at <numba.typeinfer.StaticGetItemConstraint object at 0x0000021D40ACEC88>.\n\x1b[1m\x1b[1mtuple index out of range\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: typing of static-get-item at C:\\Users\\HornLab\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\datashader\\glyphs\\line.py (653)\x1b[0m\nEnable logging at debug level for details.\n\x1b[1m\nFile "..\\..\\..\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\datashader\\glyphs\\line.py", line 653:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1mdef _xiaolinwu(i, x0, x1, y0, y1, append, *aggs_and_cols):\n    <source elided>\n    agg = aggs_and_cols[0]\n\x1b[1m    cols = aggs_and_cols[1]\n\x1b[0m    \x1b[1m^\x1b[0m\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _xiaolinwu at 0x0000021D2E0B98B8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[2] During: typing of call at <draw_segment> (33)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _xiaolinwu at 0x0000021D2E0B98B8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[4] During: typing of call at <draw_segment> (33)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m\nFile "<draw_segment>", line 33:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function draw_segment at 0x0000021D4063DAF8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[2] During: typing of call at <perform_extend_line> (13)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function draw_segment at 0x0000021D4063DAF8>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[4] During: typing of call at <perform_extend_line> (13)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m\nFile "<perform_extend_line>", line 13:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>\x1b[0m\n\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function perform_extend_line at 0x0000021D4063DE58>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[2] During: typing of call at <extend_cpu> (10)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function perform_extend_line at 0x0000021D4063DE58>))\x1b[0m\n\x1b[0m\x1b[1m[4] During: typing of call at <extend_cpu> (10)\n\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m\nFile "<extend_cpu>", line 10:\x1b[0m\n\x1b[1m<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>\x1b[0m\n')".
Invoked as dynamic_operation(height=400, scale=1.0, width=400, x_range=None, y_range=None)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj, include, exclude)
    968 
    969             if method is not None:
--> 970                 return method(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    971             return None
    972         else:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\dimension.py in _repr_mimebundle_(self, include, exclude)
   1315         combined and returned.
   1316         """
-> 1317         return Store.render(self)
   1318 
   1319 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\options.py in render(cls, obj)
   1403         data, metadata = {}, {}
   1404         for hook in hooks:
-> 1405             ret = hook(obj)
   1406             if ret is None:
   1407                 continue

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in pprint_display(obj)
    280     if not ip.display_formatter.formatters['text/plain'].pprint:
    281         return None
--> 282     return display(obj, raw_output=True)
    283 
    284 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in display(obj, raw_output, **kwargs)
    256     elif isinstance(obj, (HoloMap, DynamicMap)):
    257         with option_state(obj):
--> 258             output = map_display(obj)
    259     elif isinstance(obj, Plot):
    260         output = render(obj)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in wrapped(element)
    144         try:
    145             max_frames = OutputSettings.options['max_frames']
--> 146             mimebundle = fn(element, max_frames=max_frames)
    147             if mimebundle is None:
    148                 return {}, {}

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in map_display(vmap, max_frames)
    204         return None
    205 
--> 206     return render(vmap)
    207 
    208 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\ipython\display_hooks.py in render(obj, **kwargs)
     66         renderer = renderer.instance(fig='png')
     67 
---> 68     return renderer.components(obj, **kwargs)
     69 
     70 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py in components(self, obj, fmt, comm, **kwargs)
    408                 doc = Document()
    409                 with config.set(embed=embed):
--> 410                     model = plot.layout._render_model(doc, comm)
    411                 if embed:
    412                     return render_model(model, comm)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in _render_model(self, doc, comm)
    425         if comm is None:
    426             comm = state._comm_manager.get_server_comm()
--> 427         model = self.get_root(doc, comm)
    428 
    429         if config.embed:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\viewable.py in get_root(self, doc, comm, preprocess)
    482        
    483         doc = init_doc(doc)
--> 484         root = self._get_model(doc, comm=comm)
    485         if preprocess:
    486             self._preprocess(root)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py in _get_model(self, doc, root, parent, comm)
    111         if root is None:
    112             root = model
--> 113         objects = self._get_objects(model, [], doc, root, comm)
    114         props = dict(self._init_params(), objects=objects)
    115         model.update(**self._process_param_change(props))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\layout\base.py in _get_objects(self, model, old_objects, doc, root, comm)
    101             else:
    102                 try:
--> 103                     child = pane._get_model(doc, root, model, comm)
    104                 except RerenderError:
    105                     return self._get_objects(model, current_objects[:i], doc, root, comm)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\holoviews.py in _get_model(self, doc, root, parent, comm)
    237             plot = self.object
    238         else:
--> 239             plot = self._render(doc, comm, root)
    240 
    241         plot.pane = self

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\panel\pane\holoviews.py in _render(self, doc, comm, root)
    302                 kwargs['comm'] = comm
    303 
--> 304         return renderer.get_plot(self.object, **kwargs)
    305 
    306     def _cleanup(self, root):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\renderer.py in get_plot(self_or_cls, obj, doc, renderer, **kwargs)
     71         combining the bokeh model with another plot.
     72         """
---> 73         plot = super(BokehRenderer, self_or_cls).get_plot(obj, doc, renderer, **kwargs)
     74         if plot.document is None:
     75             plot.document = Document() if self_or_cls.notebook_context else curdoc()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py in get_plot(self_or_cls, obj, doc, renderer, comm, **kwargs)
    218 
    219         # Initialize DynamicMaps with first data item
--> 220         initialize_dynamic(obj)
    221 
    222         if not renderer:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\util.py in initialize_dynamic(obj)
    250             continue
    251         if not len(dmap):
--> 252             dmap[dmap._initial_key()]
    253 
    254 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1339         # Not a cross product and nothing cached so compute element.
   1340         if cache is not None: return cache
-> 1341         val = self._execute_callback(*tuple_key)
   1342         if data_slice:
   1343             val = self._dataslice(val, data_slice)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in _execute_callback(self, *args)
   1108 
   1109         with dynamicmap_memoization(self.callback, self.streams):
-> 1110             retval = self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
   1111         return self._style(retval)
   1112 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    712 
    713         try:
--> 714             ret = self.callable(*args, **kwargs)
    715         except KeyError:
    716             # KeyError is caught separately because it is used to signal

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs)
   1040 
   1041         def dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs):
-> 1042             key, obj = resolve(key, kwargs)
   1043             return apply(obj, *key, **kwargs)
   1044 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in resolve(key, kwargs)
   1029             elif isinstance(map_obj, DynamicMap) and map_obj._posarg_keys and not key:
   1030                 key = tuple(kwargs[k] for k in map_obj._posarg_keys)
-> 1031             return key, map_obj[key]
   1032 
   1033         def apply(element, *key, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1339         # Not a cross product and nothing cached so compute element.
   1340         if cache is not None: return cache
-> 1341         val = self._execute_callback(*tuple_key)
   1342         if data_slice:
   1343             val = self._dataslice(val, data_slice)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in _execute_callback(self, *args)
   1108 
   1109         with dynamicmap_memoization(self.callback, self.streams):
-> 1110             retval = self.callback(*args, **kwargs)
   1111         return self._style(retval)
   1112 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\spaces.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    712 
    713         try:
--> 714             ret = self.callable(*args, **kwargs)
    715         except KeyError:
    716             # KeyError is caught separately because it is used to signal

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs)
   1041         def dynamic_operation(*key, **kwargs):
   1042             key, obj = resolve(key, kwargs)
-> 1043             return apply(obj, *key, **kwargs)
   1044 
   1045         operation = self.p.operation

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in apply(element, *key, **kwargs)
   1033         def apply(element, *key, **kwargs):
   1034             kwargs = dict(util.resolve_dependent_kwargs(self.p.kwargs), **kwargs)
-> 1035             processed = self._process(element, key, kwargs)
   1036             if (self.p.link_dataset and isinstance(element, Dataset) and
   1037                 isinstance(processed, Dataset) and processed._dataset is None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init__.py in _process(self, element, key, kwargs)
   1015         elif isinstance(self.p.operation, Operation):
   1016             kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in self.p.operation.param}
-> 1017             return self.p.operation.process_element(element, key, **kwargs)
   1018         else:
   1019             return self.p.operation(element, **kwargs)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in process_element(self, element, key, **params)
    192             self.p = param.ParamOverrides(self, params,
    193                                           allow_extra_keywords=self._allow_extra_keywords)
--> 194         return self._apply(element, key)
    195 
    196 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in _apply(self, element, key)
    139             if not in_method:
    140                 element._in_method = True
--> 141         ret = self._process(element, key)
    142         if hasattr(element, '_in_method') and not in_method:
    143             element._in_method = in_method

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\operation\datashader.py in _process(self, element, key)
   1496 
   1497     def _process(self, element, key=None):
-> 1498         agg = rasterize._process(self, element, key)
   1499         shaded = shade._process(self, agg, key)
   1500         return shaded

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\operation\datashader.py in _process(self, element, key)
   1475                                        if k in transform.param})
   1476             op._precomputed = self._precomputed
-> 1477             element = element.map(op, predicate)
   1478             self._precomputed = op._precomputed
   1479 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\data\__init__.py in pipelined_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    203 
    204             try:
--> 205                 result = method_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    206                 if PipelineMeta.disable:
    207                     return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\data\__init__.py in map(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1220 
   1221     def map(self, *args, **kwargs):
-> 1222         return super(Dataset, self).map(*args, **kwargs)
   1223     map.__doc__ = LabelledData.map.__doc__
   1224 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\dimension.py in map(self, map_fn, specs, clone)
    708             return deep_mapped
    709         else:
--> 710             return map_fn(self) if applies else self
    711 
    712 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in __call__(self, element, **kwargs)
    212             elif ((self._per_element and isinstance(element, Element)) or
    213                   (not self._per_element and isinstance(element, ViewableElement))):
--> 214                 return self._apply(element)
    215         elif 'streams' not in kwargs:
    216             kwargs['streams'] = self.p.streams

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\core\operation.py in _apply(self, element, key)
    139             if not in_method:
    140                 element._in_method = True
--> 141         ret = self._process(element, key)
    142         if hasattr(element, '_in_method') and not in_method:
    143             element._in_method = in_method

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\holoviews\operation\datashader.py in _process(self, element, key)
    468 
    469         dfdata = PandasInterface.as_dframe(data)
--> 470         agg = getattr(cvs, glyph)(dfdata, x.name, y.name, agg_fn)
    471         if 'x_axis' in agg.coords and 'y_axis' in agg.coords:
    472             agg = agg.rename({'x_axis': x, 'y_axis': y})

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\core.py in line(self, source, x, y, agg, axis, geometry, antialias)
    403                            format(agg))
    404                 warnings.warn(message)
--> 405         return bypixel(source, self, glyph, agg)
    406 
    407     def area(self, source, x, y, agg=None, axis=0, y_stack=None):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\core.py in bypixel(source, canvas, glyph, agg)
   1211     with np.warnings.catch_warnings():
   1212         np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r'All-NaN (slice|axis) encountered')
-> 1213         return bypixel.pipeline(source, schema, canvas, glyph, agg)
   1214 
   1215 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\utils.py in __call__(self, head, *rest, **kwargs)
    107         typ = type(head)
    108         if typ in lk:
--> 109             return lk[typ](head, *rest, **kwargs)
    110         for cls in getmro(typ)[1:]:
    111             if cls in lk:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\data_libraries\pandas.py in pandas_pipeline(df, schema, canvas, glyph, summary)
     15 @bypixel.pipeline.register(pd.DataFrame)
     16 def pandas_pipeline(df, schema, canvas, glyph, summary):
---> 17     return glyph_dispatch(glyph, df, schema, canvas, summary)
     18 
     19 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\utils.py in __call__(self, head, *rest, **kwargs)
    110         for cls in getmro(typ)[1:]:
    111             if cls in lk:
--> 112                 return lk[cls](head, *rest, **kwargs)
    113         raise TypeError("No dispatch for {0} type".format(typ))
    114 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\data_libraries\pandas.py in default(glyph, source, schema, canvas, summary, cuda)
     43 
     44     bases = create((height, width))
---> 45     extend(bases, source, x_st + y_st, x_range + y_range)
     46 
     47     return finalize(bases,

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\glyphs\line.py in extend(aggs, df, vt, bounds, plot_start)
     71             do_extend(
     72                 sx, tx, sy, ty, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax,
---> 73                 xs, ys, plot_start, *aggs_and_cols
     74             )
     75 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in _compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    399                 e.patch_message(msg)
    400 
--> 401             error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    402         except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    403             # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\dispatcher.py in error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    342                 raise e
    343             else:
--> 344                 reraise(type(e), e, None)
    345 
    346         argtypes = []

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numba\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    666             value = tp()
    667         if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
--> 668             raise value.with_traceback(tb)
    669         raise value
    670 

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at <numba.typeinfer.StaticGetItemConstraint object at 0x0000021D40ACEC88>.
tuple index out of range
[1] During: typing of static-get-item at C:\Users\HornLab\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\glyphs\line.py (653)
Enable logging at debug level for details.

File "..\..\..\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\datashader\glyphs\line.py", line 653:
def _xiaolinwu(i, x0, x1, y0, y1, append, *aggs_and_cols):
    <source elided>
    agg = aggs_and_cols[0]
    cols = aggs_and_cols[1]
    ^

[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _xiaolinwu at 0x0000021D2E0B98B8>))
[2] During: typing of call at <draw_segment> (33)

[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function _xiaolinwu at 0x0000021D2E0B98B8>))
[4] During: typing of call at <draw_segment> (33)


File "<draw_segment>", line 33:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function draw_segment at 0x0000021D4063DAF8>))
[2] During: typing of call at <perform_extend_line> (13)

[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function draw_segment at 0x0000021D4063DAF8>))
[4] During: typing of call at <perform_extend_line> (13)


File "<perform_extend_line>", line 13:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>

[1] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function perform_extend_line at 0x0000021D4063DE58>))
[2] During: typing of call at <extend_cpu> (10)

[3] During: resolving callee type: type(CPUDispatcher(<function perform_extend_line at 0x0000021D4063DE58>))
[4] During: typing of call at <extend_cpu> (10)


File "<extend_cpu>", line 10:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

If I remove the "datashade" line and just graph the Holoviews curve graph, then it works fine. But if it was a 25 million point graph, it would take forever, hence why I need Datashader:

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, holoviews as hv
from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade
hv.extension('bokeh','matplotlib')

n = 100000
dates = pd.date_range(start='1990-01-01', freq='1T', periods=n)
curve = hv.Curve((dates,
                  np.random.normal(size=(n,)))).opts(width = 1000)
curve
```

Output graph:
[image]

Any ideas as to what could be causing this error? I can provide any additional information if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Datashader code works fine on my system:

[image]

Maybe you have some old versions, particularly of Numba?

Comment: Thanks, it was the numba version that was causing the error. There was an install error of the package "llvmlite" that would stop my version of numba from upgrading. Following the "--ignore-installed" advice found here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/NeMo/issues/841 I was finally able to upgrade numba correctly and the code runs fine now.